# Desabilitar o autocomplete de formulários em Laravel?

Tags: laravel, formulário, autocompletar

Olá. Pesquisei por toda a internet e não encontrei.

Simplesmente não consigo fazer com que o autocomplete de formulários Laravel seja desativado. O 'autocomplete="off"' pra isso, não funciona para os campos se email e senha.

Alguém tem uma alternativa pra eu fazer isso no site?

```
@extends('layouts.template')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h2>Cadastrar Usuario</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">

               {{Form::model($users, array('route' => array('user.store'),'id' => 'crud-form', 'files' => 'true'))}}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('nome', 'Nome:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('nome',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('nome'))
                        {{$errors->first('nome')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('sobrenome', 'Sobrenome:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('sobrenome',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('sobrenome'))
                        {{$errors->first('sobrenome')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('email', 'E-mail:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::email('email',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        {{$errors->first('email')}}
                    @endif
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('cpf', 'CPF:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('cpf',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('cpf'))
                        {{$errors->first('cpf')}}
                    @endif

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('rg', 'RG:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('rg',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('rg'))
                        {{$errors->first('rg')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('telefone', 'Telefone:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('telefone',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('telefone'))
                        {{$errors->first('telefone')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('celular', 'Celular:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('celular',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('celular'))
                        {{$errors->first('celular')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('rua', 'Rua:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('rua',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('rua'))
                        {{$errors->first('rua')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('bairro', 'Bairro:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('bairro',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('bairro'))
                        {{$errors->first('bairro')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('complemento', 'Complemento:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('complemento',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('numero', 'Numero:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('numero',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('numero'))
                        {{$errors->first('numero')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('cep', 'CEP:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('cep',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('cep'))
                        {{$errors->first('cep')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('datanascimento', 'Data de nascimento:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('datanascimento',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form', 'id' => 'datepicker','autocomplete' => 'off','readonly'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('dattanascimento'))
                        {{$errors->first('datanascimento')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('role', 'Função:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::select('role',array('gerente' => 'Gerente', 'vendedor' => 'Vendedor'),'vendedor',array('class' => 'tipo col-lg-8'))}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('password', 'Senha:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::password('password',['class' => 'col-lg-8 form','autocomplete' => 'off'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        {{$errors->first('pasawword')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirmação Senha:',['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::password('password_confirmation',['class' => 'col-lg-8 form'])}}
                    @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                        {{$errors->first('password_confirmation')}}
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::reset('Limpar', array('class' => 'btn'))}}
                    {{Form::submit('Salvar', array('class' => 'btn', 'id' => 'validar'))}}
                </div>

                <a href="/user" class="btn pull-left">
                    Voltar
                </a>

                {{Form::close()}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@endsection


@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>
{!! $validator->selector('#crud-form') !!}
 @endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

No seu e-mail você não está desativando. Use da seguinte forma:

```
{{Form::email('email',null,['class' => 'col-lg-8 form', 'autocomplete'=>'off'])}}
```

Acabei de testar e desativou normal.